# Not receiving push notifications on iPhone5

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented push notifications on my ios app and have tested it on my iPhone6(iOS 8.4) and its works fine.
I've some trouble making it work on my iPhone5c(iOS 8.3).

Whatever I do, I don't get any notifications. I've check the device token and it is correct so I don't have any idea why I am not receiving the notification on this phone.

I've also checked the time to live(ttl) value and it's not null so even if I lost the connection each time I am sending the notification (which isn't the case) I would/should receive it when I was going online again.

I can't do much testing/debugging on server right now so it's even harder to try to fix this issue.

**EDIT**:

Here is how I register for notifications:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0f){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:
                [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:
                    (UIUserNotificationTypeSound |
                    UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge)
    categories:nil]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
    (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
     UIUserNotificationTypeSound |
     UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you add authorization in your appDelegate?

Comment: @Masterfego yup, it wouldn't work on my iPhone6 if I hadn't

Comment: paste this sample of code please

Comment: Have you checked the notification settings on the device (app and general)?

Comment: @Masterfego Will edit post in a few secs.

Comment: @DannyBravo Bravo yes that's the first thing I've checked (both are set correctly)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who would have the same problem, ie: not receiving push notifications on a specific phone.
I've managed to make it work by doing a complete reset of the phone : **Settings** > **Generale** > **Reset** > **Delete content and settings**

Hope this helps